# "Психотронное" или "психотропное"?

Tags: лексика

Как правильно говорить: "психотроНное оружие" или "психотроПное оружие"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В словаре проф. Бельчикова и доц. Ражевой об этих паронимах сказано следующее:

*Психотропный* – влияющий на психику, на психические процессы (о лекарственных препаратах). *Психотронный* – порождаемый посредством организованного управления психикой.